# How to fix AWS security hole ALAS-2018-1045?

Tags: aws, amazon

I am researching about the security hole [CVE-2018-12020](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-12020) and learned that you need to update to min version 2.2.8 to fix the issue.

I need to fix this for my EC2. I read information from [this offical AWS report](https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2018-1045.html), and it says that the security hole will be fixed after I run `yum update gnupg gnupg2`.

In new packages session:

```
i686:
    gnupg-1.4.19-1.29.amzn1.i686
    gnupg-debuginfo-1.4.19-1.29.amzn1.i686
    gnupg2-smime-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.i686
    gnupg2-debuginfo-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.i686
    gnupg2-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.i686

src:
    gnupg-1.4.19-1.29.amzn1.src
    gnupg2-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.src

x86_64:
    gnupg-1.4.19-1.29.amzn1.x86_64
    gnupg-debuginfo-1.4.19-1.29.amzn1.x86_64
    gnupg2-smime-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.x86_64
    gnupg2-debuginfo-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.x86_64
    gnupg2-2.0.28-2.32.amzn1.x86_64
```

Why does AWS only show as version in 2.0.28, despite of the first claim that the security hole will only be fixed when you update to 2.2.8? This confuses me.

Is it a package before (was affected by this bug) or after you update (AWS fixed for this bug)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion you are facing is that Amazon & RedHat back port fixes into their known stable branch, this is to say that

gnupg2-2.0.28-2.32

Really indicates `gnupg2` core version `2.0.28` with revisions `2.32`;

If I am understanding your question correctly, you should run: `rpm -q gnupg2-2.0.28-2.32 --changelog` and inspect the changelog to ensure the installed version contains the backported fix for CVE-2018-12020

Comment: after i check by your recommendation : rpm -q gnupg2-2.0.28-2.33.amzn1.x86_64 --changelog |grep "CVE-2018-12020"
- Apply patch for CVE-2018-9234 & CVE-2018-12020
I see that this package include the fixing for the bug. Thank you so much.

Comment: aws maintains the package by themself so I think this is a reason why the have a diffrent tag version.